# How do I set something when 2 or more touches are pressed?

Tags: unity, android, touch, multitouch

I currently have a working controller with left and right but I want to set the velocity of the character to 0/Stop when 2 or more touches are detected. This is my current working code but I want to make the player stop when 2 touches are detected.

```
void TouchMove(){

    if(Input.touchCount > 0){

        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        float middle = Screen.width / 2;

        if(touch.position.x < middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            MoveRight();
        }

    }
    else {
        SetVelocityZero();
    }
}`
```

This is how my game looks like [image]

Comment: It looks like you're already reading the touch count. Have you tried checking for `if(Input.touchCount >= 2) { /* don't move */ }` ? Show us what you tried, and describe what went wrong.

Comment: Oh I see tried that earlier but I guess I wrote 
if(Input.touches >= 2){
                SetVelocityZero();
            }

Which is wrong

Comment: Feel free to add an answer showing what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem is by inserting this code in the touchmove function

`if(Input.touchCount >= 2){
   SetVelocityZero();
 }`

Thank you DMGregory for the answer!

Comment: You can also `if(Input.touchCount == 1) { /* do movement */ } else { /* stop */ }` to catch both the 0 touches and 2+ touches cases in one fell swoop.